# How does a pipe work in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, redirect, pipe

How does piping work?  If I run a program via CLI and redirect output to a file will I be able to pipe that file into another program as it is being written?

Basically when one line is written to the file I would like it to be piped immediately to my second application (I am trying to dynamically draw a graph off an existing program).  Just unsure if piping completes the first command before moving on to the next command.

Any feed back would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mentioned a CLI interface for program1 below - if program1 depends on interactive input, it's likely to be a poor candidate for direct piping like Adam's answer shows.

Comment: Piping in windows is different than in Linux...  I believe Linux uses some type of ring-buffer and uses concurrent programming theories (producer-consumer problem etc) to perform well.  I think windows waits untill the first program is done before calling the second.

Answer (score 67):

If you want to redirect the output of one program into the input of another, just use a simple pipeline:

```
program1 arg arg | program2 arg arg
```

If you want to save the output of `program1` into a file *and* pipe it into `program2`, you can use [`tee(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee):

```
program1 arg arg | tee output-file | program2 arg arg
```

All programs in a pipeline are run simultaneously.  Most programs typically use *blocking* I/O: if when they try to read their input and nothing is there, they *block*: that is, they stop, and the operating system de-schedules them to run until more input becomes available (to avoid eating up the CPU).  Similarly, if a program earlier in the pipeline is writing data faster than a later program can read it, eventually the pipe's buffer fills up and the writer blocks: the OS de-schedules it until the pipe's buffer gets emptied by the reader, and then it can continue writing again.

---

**EDIT**

If you want to use the output of `program1` as the command-line parameters, you can use the backquotes or the `$()` syntax:

```
# Runs "program1 arg", and uses the output as the command-line arguments for
# program2
program2 `program1 arg`

# Same as above
program2 $(program1 arg)
```

The `$()` syntax should be preferred, since they are clearer, and they can be nested.

Comment: For some reason the initial program (program1 in this case) does not cooperate with piping.  Is there special code needed inside of it?  I tried to do a simple pipe as you had laid out and 1) CLI interface for program1 did not start, and 2) program2 asked for parameters (though I am trying to pass the output of 1 as the parameters for 2)

Comment: @Jon, it sounds like program1 isn't sending its output to stdout or program2 isn't reading from stdin. What programs are you trying to run?

Comment: There is a flag that some programs can read to find out if they are in a pipe or not... 'ls' does this to decide how to display file information (when in a pipe, it has each file on a line of its own etc.)

Comment: @Matt, I used the example laid out in the man page for pipe and echo.  I assumed this would take an input and then print it twice or at the very least once.  Not so.  My CLI looks like $./test "testing" | echo.  Test is basically just a program that puts a string in a pipe and pulls it out character by character.

Comment: @Jon: echo doesn't read its stdin, it only looks at its command line parameters. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Adam: The test pipe I wrote above was just me trying to learn linux a little better.  The original program has too many libraries based in linux to try to do anything with it on windows.

The original program itself is a test program which takes a series of inputs to determine the appropriate output (which changes randomly and dynamically).  

The output travels though a network (or in my case to another terminal) where it is printed.  My task is to write a program which takes that input and makes it "pretty" such as a graph.

That the basic idea at least.

Comment: btw, if you want a program that reads stdin and simply repeats them to stdout, use `cat`, not `echo`.

Answer (score 34):

Piping **does not complete the first command before running the second**.  Unix (and Linux) piping run all commands concurrently.  A command will be suspended if

- It is starved for input.
- It has produced significantly more output than its successor is ready to consume.

For most programs output is *buffered*, which means that the OS accumulates a substantial amount of output (perhaps 8000 characters or so) before passing it on to the next stage of the pipeline.  This buffering is used to avoid too much switching back and forth between processes and kernel.

If you want output on a pipeline to be sent right away, you can use *unbuffered* I/O, which in C means calling something like `fflush()` to be sure that any buffered output is *immediately* sent on to the next process.  Unbuffered input is also possible but is generally unnecessary because a process that is starved for input typically does not wait for a full buffer but will process any input you can get.

For typical applications unbuffered output is not recommended; you generally get the best performance with the defaults.  In your case, however, where you want to do dynamic graphing immediately the first process has the info available, you definitely want to be using unbuffered output.  If you're using C, calling `fflush(stdout)` whenever you want output sent will be sufficient.

Answer (score 10):

If your programs are communicating using `stdin` and `stdout`, then make sure that you are either calling `fflush(stdout)` after you write or find some way to disable standard IO buffering. The best reference that I can think of that really describe how to best implement pipelines in C/C++ is [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](http://www.kohala.com/start/apue.html) or [UNIX Network Programming: Volume 2](http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv22e/unpv22e.html). You could probably start with a [this article](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) as well.

Answer (score 5):

If your two programs insist on reading and writing to files and do not use stdin/stdout, you may find you can use a **named pipe** instead of a file.

Create a named pipe with the mknod(1) command:

```
$ mknod /tmp/named-pipe p
```

Then configure your programs to read and write to /tmp/named-pipe (use whatever path/name you feel is appropriate).

In this case, both programs will run in parallel, blocking as necessary when the pipe becomes full/empty as described in the other answers.