# Do 'cat foo.txt | my_cmd' and 'my_cmd < foo.txt' accomplish the same thing?

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, pipe, stdin

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9553628/522385) helped me understand the difference between redirection and piping, but the examples focus on redirecting STDOUT (`echo foo > bar.txt`) and piping STDIN (`ls | grep foo`).

It would seem to me that any command that could be written `my_command < file.txt` could also be written `cat file.txt | my_command`. In what situations are STDIN redirection necessary?

Apart from the fact that using `cat` spawns an extra process and is less efficient than redirecting STDIN, are there situations in which you *have to* use the STDIN redirection? Put another way, is there ever a reason to pipe the output of `cat` to another command?

Comment: Redirecting standard input is certainly *preferable* to the pipe version, since it doesn't spawn an unnecessary process. A better question would be when is the *pipe* necessary.

Comment: @chepner - a pipe is certainly necessary when a *command* is generating the data that's being read on STDIN by `my_command`. And I can see how redirecting a file to STDIN (or is it "redirecting STDIN to a file"?) is more efficient. What I want to know is whether there are cases in which you can't simply pipe a file to STDIN, and have to use the STDIN-redirect method. How might I better express that in my question?

Comment: Maybe the question should be: are `cat foo.txt | my_cmd` and `my_cmd < foo.txt` effectively synonymous? (Apart from the issue of preferability)

Comment: Redirection is never *necessary*, but your question implies you think the pipe is better and redirection should be avoided when possible. The exact opposite is true: you should use redirection when possible, and only use a pipe when necessary. The pipe uses `cat` to open the file for reading when the shell is perfectly capable of opening it on its own.

Comment: @chepner I didn't mean to imply I thought it was "better." - I'd literally never thought about it before. I found myself `cat`-ing a file into a command and wondered why I have always done that (and seen it done) instead of using STDIN redirection. It's been my experience that Unix doesn't often give one "more than one way to do it."  Now all I have to do is learn new muscle memory.

Comment: If your program tries to `seek()` around or read a part of its input file more than once, it **can't** use the pipe. This means that, for example, versions of `sort` that can parallelize by starting multiple processes that handle different chunks of the input file can't offer that functionality at all when reading from `cat` (without, at least, reading everything from the FIFO into a temporary file first, rather than just being able to have each thread/subprocess seek() directly to a different piece of the input).

Comment: Consider `wc -c` for another example -- given a handle on a real file it can just use a `stat()`-family call to get the file's length in constant time no matter how long it takes. Given a pipe, it has to read the whole thing to the end and count bytes, so we're not just talking FIFO overhead but gotta-use-an-entirely-different-algorithm overhead.

Comment: (err, "no matter how long it takes" should have been "no matter how long that file is", of course).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the difference between `my_command < file.txt` and `cat file.txt | my_command`?

```
my_command < file.txt
```

The redirection symbol can also be written as `0<` as this redirects file descriptor 0 (`stdin`) to connect to `file.txt` instead of the current setting, which is probably the terminal.  If `my_command` is a shell built-in then there are NO child processes created, otherwise there is one.

```
cat file.txt | my_command
```

This redirects file descriptor 1 (`stdout`) of the command on the left to the input stream of an anonymous pipe, and file descriptor 0 (`stdin`) of the command on the right to the output stream of the anonymous pipe.

We see at once that there is a child process, since `cat` is not a shell built-in.  However in `bash` even if `my_command` is a shell builtin it is still run in a child process.  Therefore we have TWO child processes.

So the pipe, in theory, is less efficient.  Whether that difference is significant depends on many factors, including the definition of "significant".  The time when a pipe *is* preferable is this alternative:

```
command1 > file.txt
command2 < file.txt
```

Here it is likely that

```
command1 | command2
```

is more efficient, remembering that, in practice, we will probably need a third child process in `rm file.txt`.

However, there are limitations to pipes.  They are not *seekable* (random access, see `man 2 lseek`) and they cannot be *memory mapped* (see `man 2 mmap`).  Some applications map files to virtual memory, but it would be unusual to do that to `stdin` or `stdout`.  Memory mapping in particular is not possible on a pipe (whether anonymous or named) because a range of virtual addresses has to be reserved and for that a size is required.

Edit:

As mentioned by @JohnKugelman, a common error and source of many SO questions is the associated issue with a child process and redirection:

Take a file `file.txt` with 99 lines:

```
i=0
cat file.txt|while read
do
   (( i = i+1 ))
done

echo "$i"
```

What gets displayed?  The answer is `0`.  Why?  Because the count `i = i + 1` is done in a *subshell* which, in `bash`, is a child process and does not change `i` in the parent (note: this does not apply to korn shell, `ksh`).

```
while read
do
   (( i = i+1 ))
done < file.txt

echo "$i"
```

This displays the correct count because no child processes are involved.

Comment: This helped by reminding me that STDIN can sometimes be attached to, and treated as, a _file_. I'm so used to thinking of it as a terminal, or the receiving end of a pipe, that I'd forgotten that. Thanks for a thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course replace any use of input redirection with a pipe that reads from `cat`, but it is inefficient to do so, as you are spawning a new process to do something the shell can already do by itself. However, not *every* instance of `cat ... | my_command` can be replaced with `my_command < ...`, namely when `cat` is doing its intended job of concatenating two (or more) files, it is perfectly reasonable to pipe its output to another command.

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | my_command
```

Comment: I disagree that this is true of *any* redirection without qualification. It's rare for programs to `fstat` or `seek` in their stdin (except as a performance optimization), but not impossible. Trying to remember the name of a standard GNU tool that, if given a pipe, copies the pipe's whole contents to a temporary file to have a seekable source before it's able to start its work... `shuf`, maybe?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: these are exactly the situations I was interested in hearing about.