# why doesn't cat foo.txt | echo produce output?

Tags: bash, pipe, echo

I am ashamed to ask such a basic question, but it seems I have a major flaw in my understanding of pipes.  I read this:

[Do 'cat foo.txt | my_cmd' and 'my_cmd < foo.txt' accomplish the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446896/do-cat-foo-txt-my-cmd-and-my-cmd-foo-txt-accomplish-the-same-thing)

and quite a few other posts, but I cannot fathom why the mentioned statement doesn't print the contents of foo.txt.  Originally, I had tried

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1 | sort | echo
```

and eventually reduced the problem to what is listed. Interestingly, if I leave out the  pipe and echo at the end everything works mostly well- although I didn't want newlines.  I can also

```
cut -d: -f1 < /etc/passwd  | sort
```

and get the same result (also unfortunately with newlines.)  Maybe echo doesn't accept stdin? The man page doesn't mention it either way. It seems like a fairly useful addition to its functionality, but I guess it could make things more complicated if both stdin and arguments were supplied.

I know I'm being braindead about this.  Theres no rush in answering this- I'm just curious. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Standard input and command arguments are not generally interchangeable. `echo` prints what it receives as arguments, not what it receives as stdin. My answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/600253/why-is-xargs-necessary/600273#600273) might help. (Or it might just confuse things further, but hopefully not.)

Comment: Thanks Gordon. The main take-aways I got were "xargs can be thought of as converting STDIN-style input to arguments:" and echo actually does more-or-less the opposite.  Its sort of crazy how many projects I've managed to complete without even understanding what I was actually doing, just following idioms taught to be by example.

Answer (score 1):

`echo` does not read stdin - that's `cat`'s job.

As you've discovered, simply remove the `| echo` from your pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some precisions.

About `echo`:

- `echo` will never read stdin, as you can see:

  ```
  ~ $ echo HI
  HI
  ~ $ echo HI | echo LOW
  LOW
  ~ $ echo HI | echo LOW | cat
  LOW
  ~ $ echo HI | cat | echo LOW
  LOW
  ```
- `echo` is just aimed to *output* the characters that you give as parameters.
- So, piping `echo` like this: `any_command | echo` is totally useless.

About `cat`:

- `cat` will always read stdin, *unless* you give it a filename, eg:

```
 Comments      | Shell
---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
               | ~ $ cat poem.txt
               | My super poem
               | ~ $ cat poem.txt | cat | cat
               | My super poem
               | ~ $ echo HI | cat           # Read stdin because no filename
               |                             # is given
               | HI
               | ~ $ echo HI | cat poem.txt  # A filename is given, so don't
               |                             # take stdin into account
               | My super poem
               | ~ $ cat poem.txt | echo     # echo is not mean to be piped
               |
               | ~ $ cat poem.txt | echo HI  # echo is not mean to be piped
               | HI
               | ~ $ cat  # if no pipe or filename is given to cat, then a basic
               |          # interactive mode is proposed, thanks to the shell
[interactive]  | 1234
[cat response] | 1234
[interactive]  | Leave this hell by hitting Ctrl-D...
[cat response] | Leave this hell by hitting Ctrl-D...
[hit Ctrl-D]   |
               | ~ $ cat > new-poem.txt
[interactive]  | Looking at stars everyday
[interactive]  | So nice
[hit Ctrl-D]   |
               | ~ $ cat new-poem.txt
               | Looking at stars everyday
               | So nice
```