# Serial interface permanently denies requests

Tags: serial-port

my actual problem is, that every time i want to access my serial interface (Arduino), the system returns **Permission denied** .

```
root@laptop:/home/user #> cu -l /dev/ttyACM0 -s 115200
/usr/bin/cu: open (/dev/ttyACM0): Permission denied
/usr/bin/cu: /dev/ttyACM0: Line in Use

root@laptop:/home/user #> ls -la /dev/ttyACM*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Mär 14 10:37 /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Mär 14 10:37 /dev/ttyACM1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Mär 14 10:37 /dev/ttyACM2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Mär 14 10:37 /dev/ttyACM3
```

what is another location to seek for the reason of this error?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Serial ports cannot be shared.  Find the other program that's using the port and kill it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never used Arduino, so I'll suppose your method is right. First thing I would try is `sudo`ing the first command:

```
sudo cu -l /dev/ttyACM0 -s 115200
```

But, since the second message is `Line in Use` it might also be that the `/dev/ttyACM0` is already actually taken/locked. In other words, is there any process using the port? I can't test it on a serial port, but I'd try [piping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1072135/679982) the output of [list open files](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) command to [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) command:

```
lsof | grep ACM
```

It **should** list the [process identifer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) of the process which locked upon the port. Then you can use the [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) command to stop that process:

```
kill <PID_FROM_OUTPUT_OF_UPPER_COMMAND>
```

To verify that you succesfully stopped the process you can pipe the output of [list all active processes](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps) command to the grep command:

```
ps x | grep <PID_FROM_OUTPUT_OF_UPPER_COMMAND>
```

which should return no output if the process was successfully stopped. If not, it will ouput that line, so you can try with the -9 flag like this:

```
kill -9 <PID_FROM_OUTPUT_OF_UPPER_COMMAND>
```

and it will eventually stop.

Without testing, I'm not sure will the `lsof` command written in the current form list the taken `tty` devices. If that is the case then there must be some flag combination which will list them, since everything in Unix is a file.

So, the principle must be valid: find out which process is using the device and stop it (the `ps` and `kill` commands will work once you have the right process identifier).

If all of the above is not the case, then **probably** your method is wrong. In that case, I'd start by carefully rereading the Arduino documentation again :)

Comment: within lsof I don't get any files.
Starting cu with sudo doesn't help either.

Comment: This is a really ugly advice, but might help: reset the computer - unless someone is taking the port upon booting or starting the processes you start it will work. If that doesn't help, the only advice I can give you is **carefully** rereading the docs again :)

Comment: I've found the problem :) Even if you are root you are not allowed to access this device. You have to be member of the dialout group! But thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

As HappyHacking mentioned you need to execute the following command:

`sudo adduser [user] dialout`

Then logout of the user and log back in.

Answer (score 1):

I created new file in /etc/udev/rules.d/51-arduino.rule with following content:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyACM0", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0043", GROUP="dialout", MODE="0666"
```

Be careful to set up idVendor and idProduct properly. After reboot the device privileges are set.