# How do I create a RegEx which has multiple criteria?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, logical-operators

I am working through a lab on RegEx which asks me to:

> Search the 'countries' file for all the words with nine characters and
>   the letter i.
> How many results are found?

I am working in a generic Linux command prompt in a online emulated environment. I am allowed to use `grep`, `awk` or `sed` though I am feeling a preference for `grep`.

(I am 100% a noob when it comes to RegEx so *please* explain it to me like I'm 5)

Per a previous lab I already used something like below which finds me all countries which have 9 characters, however I cannot find a way to make it find all words which have 9 characters AND contain the letter `i` in any position.

```
grep -E '\b\w{9}\b' countries
```

The `|` operator does not help because its an `OR` operator and will find me all instances that `i` is found, and all words which are 9 characters and I need both to happen at the same time. I tried multiple `grep` statements as well and it seems the emulator may not accept that.

I am also trying to stick to `[]` character sets as the next question asks for multiple letters within the 9 letter word.

Comment: Hello Jen, welcome to Stack Overflow. See if one of these answers your question: [regex AND operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/470602/7586), [regex for password strength](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19605150/7586) - they are not *exactly* what you need (not `grep` questions, and they usually assume you're matching the whole input, not just a part of it), but they answer a very similar case and explain how to combine different requirements.

Comment: Do you know [regex101](https://regex101.com/) ? It also gives you an explanation - which may help you understand why your attempt is not working for you.

Comment: @Abra online regex helpers are nice, but it also depends on whether they support cli tools, regex101 as far as I know doesn't and BRE/ERE regex features vary significantly compared to those found in programming languages

Comment: Jen, it would help if you clarify if an input line contains only one word or not.. if it is one country per line, `awk` would be better suited, for ex: `awk '/^\w{9}$/ && /i/'`

Comment: If you post sample input and expected output then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of solving this problem is to use `grep` twice, and pipe one result to the next.

First, we find all words with length 9, like you did on the previous exercise:

```
grep -Eo '\b\w{9}\b' countries
```

I'm using the flag `o` that lists only the matching words, printing one word per line.
Next, we use [Linux pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1072125/7586) (not regex OR) to feed the output of the first `grep` to a second `grep`:

```
grep -Eo '\b\w{9}\b' countries | grep 'i'
```

The final output will be all words with nine characters and `i`.

Depending on your requirements, this approach may be considered "cheating" if you're more focused on Regex, but a good solution if you're also learning Linux.

---

The fact you are looking for *words* complicates the regex (in contrary to *lines* in the file), but it is also possible to come up with a single regex to match these words.

```
 \b(?=\w*i)\w{9}\b
```

This builds on `\b\w{9}\b` you already have. `(?=\w*i)` is the `AND` condition. After we find the beginning of the word (`\b`), we [look ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973609/7586) for `\w*i` (zero or more letters, and then our `i`). We're using `\w*` in the lookahead, not `.*`, so we are looking at the *same word*. `(?=.*i)` would have matched any `i` also **after** the nine characters.
After finding the `i`, we continue to make sure the word is only 9 letters.

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/G5EVdM/1

Comment: Sorry, I missed the statement "I tried multiple grep statements as well and it seems the emulator may not accept that." from the question - I see you already tried that one.

Comment: fyi: typically, grep/sed/awk/etc are based on BRE/ERE and do not have support for lookarounds, non-greedy, etc. If `GNU grep` is available with PCRE option, then the lookaround solution would work

Comment: @Sundeep - how typical would you say that is? I thought the -E option is pretty common.

Comment: By default, grep uses BRE and -E enables ERE. How they behave depends on implementation. For GNU grep, features are same, only syntax differs - for example `\?` in BRE is `?` in ERE. To use PCRE (perl compatible regex), need to use -P option and as far as I know, only GNU grep supports that

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y would be a good place for more details