# put grep output at the end of another line into another file

Tags: bash, sed, grep, filtering

I got a list containing movie names like this

```
Film Name - Film.information.lanugage.2160p.more.info
Film Name - Film.info.information.1080p.more.info
Film Name - Film.information.lanugage.1080p.information.info
Film Name - Film.information.more.720p.more.info
Film Name - Film.more.lanugage.2160p.more.info
```

I am using `grep '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]p' list.txt > resolution.txt`  to filter the resolution. And I will search for a sed cmd to delete everything with and past the `-`

Should look smth like this I think
`sed 's/-.*$//g' list.txt > cleanList.txt`
after that I want to add the resolution from the resolution.txt to the end of the lines from the cleanList.txt

the final file should look like this

```
Film Name 2160p
Film Name 1080p
Film Name 1080p
Film Name 720p
Film Name 2160p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/(.*) - (.*[^0-9])?((480|720|1080|1440|2160|4320)p?)([^0-9].*)?/\1 \3/' list.txt > output.txt
```

*Details*:

- `(.*)` - matches and captures into Group 1 as many any chars as possible
- `-`  - space + `-` + space
- `(.*[^0-9])?` - Group 2 (optional): any text and then a non-digit char
- `((480|720|1080|1440|2160|4320)p?)` - Group 3: any of the common resolution values (in Group 4) and then an optional `p`
- `([^0-9].*)?` - Group 5 (optional): a non-digit char and then any text.

The `\1 \2` replacement replaces the matched line with Group 1 + space + Group 2 values.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/RwxxfR):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='Film Name - Film.information.lanugage.2160p.more.info
Film Name - name name - Film.info.information.1080p.more.info
Star Wars - Episode V - Das Imperium schlägt zurück - Star.Wars.Episode.V.Das.Imperium.schlaegt.zurueck.1980.German.DL.2160p.UHD.BluRay.x265-ENDSTATiON
Film Name - Film.information.lanugage.1080p.information.info
Film Name - asfasfaf - Film.information.more.720p.more.info
Film Name - Film.more.lanugage.2160p.more.info
Boss Baby - Schluss mit Kindergarten - pso-bossbaby2_bd.1080p
Sicario 2 - encounters-si2so_1080p
Skyscraper - encounters-skyscraper_1080p
Unsere Zeit ist jetzt - roor-unserezeit-1080p
Schindlers Liste - d-schindlersliste-1080p
South Park: Der Film – größer, länger, ungeschnitten - in-southpark1080p
Ein Hund namens Palma - rf-ehnp2021.1080
Taxi Driver (1976) - d-taxidriver-1080p
The Taking of Deborah Logan - The.Taking.of.Deborah.Logan.2014.LIMITED.1080p.BluRay.X264-CADAVER
Die Feuerzangenbowle 1944 - d-feuerzangenbowle-1080p
Hooligans - rsg-hooligans-1080p
Geständnisse - Confessions - wombat-gestaendnisse-1080p
Greyhound - greyhound.2020.german.dl.1080p.web.h264-wayne'
 
sed -E 's/(.*) - (.*[^0-9])?((480|720|1080|1440|2160|4320)p?)([^0-9].*)?/\1 \3/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Film Name 2160p
Film Name - name name 1080p
Star Wars - Episode V - Das Imperium schlägt zurück 2160p
Film Name 1080p
Film Name - asfasfaf 720p
Film Name 2160p
Boss Baby - Schluss mit Kindergarten 1080p
Sicario 2 1080p
Skyscraper 1080p
Unsere Zeit ist jetzt 1080p
Schindlers Liste 1080p
South Park: Der Film – größer, länger, ungeschnitten 1080p
Ein Hund namens Palma 1080
Taxi Driver (1976) 1080p
The Taking of Deborah Logan 1080p
Die Feuerzangenbowle 1944 1080p
Hooligans 1080p
Geständnisse - Confessions 1080p
Greyhound 1080p
```

Comment: Hey, thank you too for the solution. But I got one more question. Sometimes the movie name contains an additional " - ". Whats the best way to solve that?

Comment: @FakeCake Did you test this solution with any of those? It will work.

Comment: Well, sometimes it works
Sometimes it doesnt
https://ideone.com/Xgxv9Y

Comment: @FakeCake Ok, so the dot before resolution can be any non-alphanumeric, right? Oh, I see that `p` may be missing.

Comment: Sometimes the resolution is not divided by a non-alphanumeric. and yea i also noticed the p is missing but do not mind that. I will sort them out.

Comment: @FakeCake I have updated the solution to account for non-digit chars on both ends of the resolution value and supporting only common resolution values.

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot! I still have to learn a lot. :D

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `awk` which gives you a cleaner solution, in one pass, rather than using `grep` and `sed`.

Try:

```
awk -F" - " '{match($2, "[0-9]+p"); print $1, substr ($2, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' list.txt > cleanList.txt
```

I use the string `" - "` as field separator between `$1` and `$2` on each input line.

The function `match()` looks for some regex corresponding to digits followed by the letter `p` inside of `$2`. This function sets the variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` in a way that is suitable for the function `substr()` to extract the matching pattern and to print it.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the suggestion. Works perfect with one exception. Some movie names contain a second " - ". How do I only delete everything with and past the last one?

Comment: @FakeCake: That's a different problem. I suggest you to post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pipe '|' operand to pass the output of one command as the input of a second command.
For example:

grep '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]p' list.txt | sed 's/-.*$//g' list.txt > cleanList.txt

If you want to save the output of the first to a file AND process it with the second, you should use the command tee (tree) to write the same output to both.
Example:
grep '...' list.txt | tee resolution.txt | sed '...' > cleanList.txt

See:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tee-command-linux-example/
[How to redirect output to a file and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout)
[How does a pipe work in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072125/how-does-a-pipe-work-in-linux)